# How do I clean mold off my bathroom ceiling?

Tags: bathroom, ceiling, cleaning, mold

So I live in an apartment and there are black spots all over my bathroom ceiling. I assume it's mold. I've kind of avoided dealing with it because it's on the ceiling which makes it harder to clean. However, inspections are coming up so I gotta deal with it.

[image]
[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you edit in a picture of the mold? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I took pictures but apparently the file sizes are too big to upload.

Comment: Post the URLs, and someone will be along to edit them in.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/F5TEcNx.jpg https://i.imgur.com/dtsoKcI.jpg

Comment: They worked as-is. I'm guessing you tried pasting them from your clipboard; for some reason the editor thinks they're much bigger that way. Just using the URL worked.

Comment: Some of this may be behavior related. After your shower run the exhaust fan until the room drys out, if the exhaust fan doesn't work have the landlord fix it. Leave the door open after your shower to help the room dry out. Make sure the vent is open so your heat/AC blows air into the room.

Answer (score 1):

White distilled vinegar works great. Just put it in a spray bottle and spray on to the moldy surface. Wait an hour and then wipe down surface with water. I used to use bleach but it only really works on non porous surfaces.

Does your bathroom vent well? Try to determine the cause of the mold and fix it. Also, don't let it build up until the next inspections. good luck.

Comment: Good advice I like hydrogen peroxide but 3% is stronger than most have and white vinegar is another form of acid that works and in my opinion won’t stink like bleach , another treatment many people use.

Comment: I'll have try that. I did try the Clorox bleach spray and a scrub brush but that really wasn't helping much.

Comment: I take hot showers so I'm guessing it's the steam causing moisture buildup.

Comment: So anyways... I tried the white distilled vinegar but it didn't really help. :( I feel like the damage might already be done.

Comment: @Matt  the vinegar will kill the mold but not necessarily remove the stains.

Comment: Well any idea how to get rid of the stains?

Comment: If the bleach didn't remove the stains then you're looking at a coat of stain blocker and some primer and paint.  Then replace the vents.

Comment: Okay the bleach seems to be working (kinda). https://i.imgur.com/Z0eXmzQ.jpg https://i.imgur.com/mKMw6HK.jpg

Comment: It might take an application or two, or three...... that what it takes for my deck to get rid on the mildew......